# When I add the option net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 in kernel command, the IP route is wrong

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ethernet, rhel7

I appended two options `net.ifnames=0` `biosdevname=0` to `grub2` because I want to change default network name to old name `eth0` on **RHEL 7**.

After that, I edited `/etc/sysconfig/network` to set default gateway for machine:

`GATEWAY=192.168.88.1`

And configured network interface. When I have only one network interface `eth0`, everything works well.

Here is the route table with one network interface `eth0`:

```
[root@devmachine ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
[root@devmachine ~]#
```

But I got the issue with route table, when more than one network interface online.

```
[root@devmachine ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth1
172.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 eth1
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth1
[root@devmachine ~]#
```

As you can see, gateway address `192.168.88.1` was added to `eth1` at the last line. And the gateway address is appended continuously with new network interface.

```
[root@devmachine network-scripts]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
default         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth1
default         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    102    0        0 eth2
172.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 eth1
172.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     101    0        0 eth2
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth1
192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    101    0        0 eth2
```

Actually, the issue appears only when i appended the option `net.ifnames=0` to `grub2`. Someone help me please.

Comment: I found the solution for my question at:
http://serverfault.com/questions/750950/route-table-issue-when-i-appended-option-net-ifnames-0-to-grub2

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be possible due to missing ifcfg-eth1

```
# cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
# cp ifcfg-eth0 ifcfg-eth1
```